# Python3 socket: socket.gethostbyname_ex at Ubuntu 16.06

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm using the socket module to get the IP address of a device automatically. I tried my code under Ubuntu 16.06 and it doesn't work anymore. I guess that this is connected to some changes. While "ifconfig" doesn't work anymore, I use "ip addr show" to get the IP address.

Until now I used the following lines:

```
# tuple of ips from all network interfaces
ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
```

Does someone has experience with it? I really would like to keep on using "socket" instead a workaround. 
But I was thinking about to call "ip addr show" and to parse the output from the command line.

Any ideas?

Alex

Comment: How is configured your computer? Has it an IP-v4 address?

Comment: Does `socket.getaddrinfo` work for you?

Comment: I figured out that the problem is related to a further DNS problem I have. So the command "socket.getaddrinfo(host, port)" works. I tried it with "google.de" but it doesn't work for my own hostname. It doesn't recognize its own fqdn correctly. If I use "socket.gethostname()" and add the domain name manually it works fine.